# Determining a Start Date within a subset group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a result set that I need to apply grouping within. However, the grouping is not just a simply group by clause (at least that I can figure out).

Some of our animals (I work at a very large animal shelter) require a veterinarian to check on them. Someone will enter "VET CHECK" on the animal's record. The history is stored so when I'm visually looking at the history, I can determine when the animal was first placed on VET CHECK and when it was removed. The issue I'm having is that I need to determine this in code and can't seem to come up with a solution. The code below will create the table and the sample data is a good representation of what most animals who require to see the vet will look like.

After creating the table and inserting the data, select * and sort by stamp desc. You'll see a VET CHECK (looking in the outcome_request field) was entered on 1/15 at 7:18 AM. If I run the report before 7:18 am, it shouldn't show the animal on VET CHECK status at all (note the NULL in the previous record). After 7:18 am (and until 1/16 at 2:07 pm), it should show the animal on VET CHECK status. If there was ONLY one VET CHECK during the animal's stay, I could simply use MIN(stamp) to get the date the animal was placed on status. However, you'll notice this animal had several different times it was on status.

Looking further down the result set, you'll it was placed on status on 1/10 at 12:07 pm and removed from status on 1/14 at 4:02 pm. If I run the report prior to 1/10 at 12:07 pm, the animal should not show on status. Running the report ANY time between 1/10 at 12:07 pm and 1/14 at 4:02 pm, the animal should show on status and the first date on status should show as 1/10. Again, I can't just use MIN(stamp) for this since there are multiple VET CHECK statuses.

```
CREATE TABLE kennel_history([kh_identity] [int] NOT NULL,
                            [kennel_identity] [int] NOT NULL,
                            [stamp] [datetime] NULL,
                            [userid] [varchar](8) NULL,
                            [impound_no] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
                            [kennel_no] [varchar](10) NULL,
                            [kennel_stat] [varchar](10) NULL,
                            [hold_notify] [varchar](1) NULL,
                            [outcome_request] [varchar](10) NULL
);

INSERT INTO kennel_history
VALUES (9471697,881929,'2019-01-17 08:05:41','CHEITMAN','K18-847522','QCB','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9471254,881929,'2019-01-16 14:07:18','THUTCHIN','K18-847522','QCE','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9469550,881929,'2019-01-15 07:18:36','BBUSCEMI','K18-847522','QCE','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9469390,881929,'2019-01-14 16:56:02','LRAYNER','K18-847522','QCE','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9469302,881929,'2019-01-14 16:02:41','SHUNT','K18-847522','QRL03','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9467613,881929,'2019-01-13 08:30:46','DEADS','K18-847522','QRL03','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9465923,881929,'2019-01-11 10:16:52','DEADS','K18-847522','QRL06','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9465225,881929,'2019-01-10 12:07:17','KMORRIS','K18-847522','QRL03','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9465224,881929,'2019-01-10 12:07:07','KMORRIS','K18-847522','QRL03','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9463051,881929,'2019-01-08 06:43:19','CSILVEY','K18-847522','QRL03','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9461197,881929,'2019-01-06 09:24:07','APENAZUR','K18-847522','QRL08','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9460067,881929,'2019-01-05 08:57:46','APENAZUR','K18-847522','QRL07','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9459250,881929,'2019-01-04 10:13:45','DEADS','K18-847522','QRL01','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9458551,881929,'2019-01-03 12:30:42','ACLARK','K18-847522','QRL08','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9458499,881929,'2019-01-03 11:51:48','AGARFIAS','K18-847522','DHC04','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9458484,881929,'2019-01-03 11:48:32','AGARFIAS','K18-847522','DHC04','AVAILABLE',NULL,NULL),
(9454810,881929,'2018-12-29 12:20:01','ACLARK','K18-847522','DHC04','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9454683,881929,'2018-12-29 11:08:39','AGARFIAS','K18-847522','SXA24','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9454680,881929,'2018-12-29 11:06:32','AGARFIAS','K18-847522','SXA24','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9454511,881929,'2018-12-29 09:13:22','BBUSCEMI','K18-847522','SXA24','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9453649,881929,'2018-12-28 08:46:12','TSIMONS','K18-847522','SXA24','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET TECH'),
(9453648,881929,'2018-12-28 08:46:07','TSIMONS','K18-847522','SXA24','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9453624,881929,'2018-12-28 08:03:19','BBUSCEMI','K18-847522','SXA24','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET TECH'),
(9453533,881929,'2018-12-27 17:45:22','DEADS','K18-847522','DO03','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET TECH'),
(9453405,881929,'2018-12-27 15:28:02','DEADS','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET TECH'),
(9452597,881929,'2018-12-26 15:27:48','SSUTTON','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9452426,881929,'2018-12-26 13:05:26','THUTCHIN','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9452121,881929,'2018-12-26 10:18:55','THUTCHIN','K18-847522','SXA04','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9451959,881929,'2018-12-26 08:09:21','BBUSCEMI','K18-847522','SXA04','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9451886,881929,'2018-12-25 14:12:49','SBUCKMAN','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9451884,881929,'2018-12-25 14:11:58','SBUCKMAN','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9451870,881929,'2018-12-25 13:28:15','SBUCKMAN','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9450863,881929,'2018-12-23 17:24:17','BLAEHLE','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9449482,881929,'2018-12-22 13:12:34','V-KTAYLO','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9448808,881929,'2018-12-21 16:23:03','SBUCKMAN','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET CHECK'),
(9448111,881929,'2018-12-21 09:10:49','CHEITMAN','K18-847522','DO02','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9448069,881929,'2018-12-21 08:36:47','BMERMAN','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9447864,881929,'2018-12-20 17:32:53','DEADS','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL','Y','VET TECH'),
(9446090,881929,'2018-12-19 09:54:33','MGELTZ','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9445884,881929,'2018-12-19 07:25:51','ZKNOX','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL','Y','PRIORITY 1'),
(9444928,881929,'2018-12-18 08:22:30','EKNEPPER','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL','Y','PRIORITY 1'),
(9438860,881929,'2018-12-12 09:15:33','CMCCANN','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL),
(9438820,881929,'2018-12-12 08:21:33','JAUSEC','K18-847522','DO07','UNAVAILABL',NULL,NULL);
```

Somehow, I have to take into account the records on either side of the status where outcome_request IS NULL so I know when the status starts and stops. This one has me stumped.

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is an "animal" and an "animal's stay" in terms of your data? I don't see absolutely unambiguous columns for `CritterGUID` and `CheckInDate`/`CheckOutDate` (and `TurndownServiceDeclined`). (Aside: Kudos for providing DDL and consumable data in your question.)

Comment: This sample data represents just one animal. There is an animal_id field which I didn't include here. The kennel_identity is created when the animal is brought in to us (also referred to as impounded) which is why kennel_identity and impound_no are the same for all of the history records. kh_identity is an identity field which is why you see it higher for each record.

The KENNEL table is where the kennel_history records are coming from. KENNEL contains a single record for each time an animal is impounded. Most animals are here only once but sometimes they come back for various reasons.

Comment: Also didn't mention that the KENNEL table contains the dates the animal comes in to our care and leaves our care. There is also an ANIMAL table to record specifics of each animal such as breed, color, sex, species, etc., where the animal_id field is the key.

Comment: can you also post the desired resultset when the report is run for different dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share my ultimate solution. Using the answer posted above from IsItGreyOrGray (thank you for spurring the creative juices and your answer is what made me select this path) combined with feedback on another forum and what I got back from our vendor, my ultimate solution was to create a function to get the desired date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION StartDateOnOutcomeRequest (@KennelIdentity INT,
                                           @OutcomeRequest VARCHAR(10),
                                           @DBStamp        DATETIME)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    /* This section for testing. Leave commented out for normal execution.
    DECLARE @KennelIdentity INT = 881929;
    DECLARE @OutcomeRequest VARCHAR(10) = 'ADOPTIONS';
    DECLARE @DBStamp        DATETIME = '2019-01-21 12:56:17.457';
    */

    DECLARE @CurrentRowNum  INT;
    DECLARE @StartRowNum    INT;
    DECLARE @StartDate      DATETIME;
    DECLARE @RowNumTmp TABLE (RowNumber      INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                              KHIdentity     INT,
                              OutcomeRequest VARCHAR(10),
                              Stamp          DATETIME);

    -- Load kennel history records into temp table with seqential row number.
    INSERT INTO @RowNumTmp (KHIdentity,
                            OutcomeRequest,
                            Stamp)
    SELECT kh_identity,
           ISNULL(outcome_request, 'None'),
           stamp
    FROM   SYSADM.kennel_history
    WHERE (kennel_identity = @KennelIdentity)
    ORDER BY kh_identity;

    -- Identify the history record matching the database timestamp and outcome request type. Store that record's row number in a variable.
    SELECT @CurrentRowNum = RowNumber
    FROM   @RowNumTmp
    WHERE (Stamp = @DBStamp)
      AND (OutcomeRequest = @OutcomeRequest);

    -- Identify the first row number on the current outcome request by looking at lesser rows where the outcome request does not match.
    SELECT @StartRowNum = MAX(RowNumber) + 1
    FROM   @RowNumTmp
    WHERE (RowNumber <= @CurrentRowNum)
      AND (OutcomeRequest <> @OutcomeRequest);

    -- Finally, get the date using the starting row number for the outcome request and return it below.
    SELECT @StartDate = Stamp
    FROM   @RowNumTmp
    WHERE (RowNumber = @StartRowNum);

    RETURN(@StartDate);
END;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT k.KENNEL_NO AS KennelNumber,
       ISNULL(k.KENNEL_STAT, '') AS KennelStatus,
       ISNULL(k.kennel_substat, '') AS KennelSubstatus,
       a.ANIMAL_ID AS AnimalId,
       a.ANIMAL_TYPE AS AnimalType,
       a.age_long AS AgeLong,
       CASE
            WHEN a.SECONDARY_BREED IS NULL THEN a.PRIMARY_BREED
            ELSE a.PRIMARY_BREED + ' / ' + a.SECONDARY_BREED
       END + ' / ' + 
       CASE
            WHEN a.SECONDARY_COLOR IS NULL THEN a.PRIMARY_COLOR
            ELSE a.PRIMARY_COLOR + ' / ' + a.SECONDARY_COLOR
       END AS BreedColor,
       dbo.StartDateOnOutcomeRequest(k.kennel_identity, k.OUTCOME_REQUEST, k.STAMP) AS FirstHoldDate,
       DATEDIFF(DD, dbo.StartDateOnOutcomeRequest(k.kennel_identity, k.OUTCOME_REQUEST, k.STAMP), GETDATE()) AS DaysOnHold,
       k.extra3 AS [Level],
       ISNULL(k.OUTCOME_TYPE, '') AS OutcomeType
FROM   SYSADM.KENNEL AS k
       INNER JOIN SYSADM.ANIMAL AS a ON k.ANIMAL_ID = a.ANIMAL_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the desired result set, this is really just a SWAG...

I set up a function that takes a date specification and returns all the information pertaining to the current status as of that provided date, as well as the *userid* and *stamp* values associated with when this particular status span started.

So results for '2019-01-10 12:06:00.000' look like this:[image]

...and results for '2019-01-12 15:00:00.000' look like this:

[image]

You can test it here: https://rextester.com/XATW78525
In the test, I added some information for two additional animals - switching around some values for *stamp*, *userid*, and *outcome_request*. The function should provide the status for each animal with a record at the time.

The way I approached it was to use a CTE to build an initial result set that uses LAG to also store the previous outcome_request for the animal. Once I had that, I joined two subqueries using the CTE (one to get the most recent status and one to identify the initial instance of when the status span started) to get the results for each animal. The logic could be pulled out of the function and run explicitly, but it was easier to test a series of dates this way. It could probably be cleaned up with more coffee...

```
CREATE FUNCTION StatusAtTime (@RequestedTime DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH statusBuilder AS
    (
        SELECT
            kh1.*,
            lag(kh2.[outcome_request]) OVER (PARTITION BY kh2.[kennel_identity] ORDER BY kh2.[stamp]) AS [lagged_outcome_request]
        FROM dbo.kennel_history kh1
        JOIN dbo.kennel_history kh2
            ON kh2.[stamp] = kh1.[stamp]
            AND kh2.[kennel_identity] = kh1.[kennel_identity]
        WHERE kh1.[stamp] <= @RequestedTime 
    )

    SELECT 
        SB1.[kh_identity]
        ,SB1.[kennel_identity]
        ,SB1.[stamp]
        ,SB1.[userid]
        ,SB1.[impound_no]
        ,SB1.[kennel_no]
        ,SB1.[kennel_stat]
        ,SB1.[hold_notify]
        ,SB1.[outcome_request]
        ,SB2.[userid] AS [initial_outcome_request_userid]
        ,SB2.[stamp] AS [initial_outcome_request_stamp]
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1  WITH ties *
            FROM statusBuilder 
            ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY statusBuilder.kennel_identity ORDER BY statusBuilder.stamp desc) 
        ) SB1
    JOIN 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1  WITH ties *
            FROM statusBuilder 
            WHERE ISNULL([outcome_request],'NullOutcome') <> ISNULL([lagged_outcome_request],'NullOutcome')
            ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY statusBuilder.kennel_identity ORDER BY statusBuilder.stamp desc)
        )SB2
    ON SB1.kennel_identity = SB2.kennel_identity
)
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I have never used the functions you're using so I'm not sure what the code is trying to do. It looks like initial_outcome_request_stamp is what I'm hoping to get from this. I'm only looking for the start date for VET CHECK. When run for 1/15/2019 at 7:08 am, it look like it is getting the NULL value just before the check that is entered at 7:18. When run at 7:19 am (second query), it is still returning the same NULL value from the previous record. What I would expect at 7:19 is the datetime returned to to be 1/15/2019 07:18:00, the start of that check.

Comment: When run on 1/10 at 12:06 pm, I would expect the null returned for the date. Then, when run any time between 1/10 at 12:07 pm and 1/14 at 4:01 pm, the initial_outcome_request_stamp should be 1/10/2019 12:07:00, the start of that check.